# getting extra 0 using getstatusoutput command python

Tags: django, python-2.7, command-line, putty, freeswitch

```
live_calls = commands.getstatusoutput('/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli -x "show calls")

current_live_agent = commands.getstatus('/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli -x "show bridged_calls"  |tail -2 | grep -o "[0-9]*"')   
print(current_live_agent)
```

I am using above commands then getting out like (0 '0') i want to get first 0 only. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`commands.getstatusoutput` returns a tuple: `(status, output)`. So, to access the status (first element):

```
live_calls = commands.getstatusoutput('/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli -x "show calls"')
print("status: {0}".format(live_calls[0]))
print("output: {0}".format(live_calls[1]))
```